# Show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3+n}{5+n}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How to show that the following series converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3+n}{5+n}\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}$$

I tried to use [Direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3+n}{5+n}\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}<\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{3+n}{5+n}$$

Using the nth term test we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3+n}{5+n}=1$$

So the right series is divergent, but this tells nothing about the convergence of the left series (the test is test is inconclusive).moreover concludes that we cannot use  [Absolute Convergence Test](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/absolute_convergence.html).

On the other hand I tried to use [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), but as it was seen, at least one of the conditions does not hold, since:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3+n}{5+n}=1\neq 0$$

So Alternating series test is also inconclusive.

So what should I do?

Comment: The direct comparison test is for series of non-negative numbers. That's not the case here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{3+n}{5+n}=0$, your series diverges.

Comment: Alternating series test says : If  $\left|a_{n}\right|$  decreases monotonically and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$$Then the alternating series converges, but it does not claim "if at least one of the two conditions does not hold, then the alternating series diverges" so why I'm wrong?

Comment: Why do you say that you were wrong? You were right: the alternating series test is inconclusive here and so I took another approach.

Comment: But what approach did you use? I'm asking since this is like the nth term test, but it's the alternating one and so that's why I cannot understand what method has been used here

Comment: I used the proposition that says that if a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

José Santos is correct; however if you want an actual proof (by contradiction):
Suppose the series converges. This implied that the associated sequence is Cauchy:  by definition, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for every $n,m>n_0$ it holds
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{3+k}{5+k}(-1)^{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3+k}{5+k}(-1)^{k+1}\right|\leq \epsilon.
\end{align}
Take $m=n+1$ and $\epsilon=1/2$. Then since $\frac{3+n}{5+n}\to 1$, take $n_0$ so large that $\left|\frac{3+n}{5+n}-1\right|\leq 1/4$ for every $n>n_0$. Then
\begin{align*}
&\left|\frac{3+(n+1)}{5+(n+1)}(-1)^{n+2}-\frac{3+n}{5+n}(-1)^{n+1}\right|=\\
=&\frac{3+(n+1)}{5+(n+1)}+\frac{3+n}{5+n}\geq 2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right).
\end{align*}
This contradicts the first estimate with $\epsilon$.

This proof actually works with any series of sequences which does not converge to $0$, which is why this is always necessary.